# Is there any way to change the snooze time for alarms on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

It seems that the default snooze time for alarms is 9 minutes. Is there any way I can change this setting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A primitive work around would be to set two alarms, both with no snooze. Alarm 2 can be set X minutes after Alarm 1.

Comment: More robust method is to enable snooze for the second alarm.

Answer (score 8):

There's no obvious way to change the snooze interval for the built-in iOS alarm. However, there are a few free apps available from iTunes App Store that offer this functionality:

1. [Theme Clock Alarm](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/theme-clock-alarm/id342151239?mt=8): `Snooze timer configuration (up to 60 minutes)`
2. [Alarmed](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarmed-reminders-timers-alarm/id371886784?mt=8): offer multiple snooze timings - `Drop-down panel for easy access to key features, including Nag-Me, snoozing options...`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the alarm app are CalAlarm and Snooze Me. Both apps provide a snooze function.
CalAlarm is an calendar app, while Snooze Me is a calendar app add on.
Both apps let you choose a Snooze interval and Snooze your events.

App store link Snooze Me: http://itunes.apple.com/app/snooze-me/id474192688

App store link CalAlarm: http://itunes.apple.com/app/calendar-alarm/id367803799

Comment: Just a note - as of Oct 2015 neither is available in the UK Store.