# How can I make a calendar appointment reminder remind me "5 minutes later" on iPhone like BlackBerry?

Tags: iphone, calendar, ios

Confession, I have just converted from BlackBerry to iPhone. On BlackBerry, if I had an event in my calendar with a reminder set for 15 minutes before the event, it have the option of dismissing the reminder or let it remind again in 5 minutes. I have been unable to find anything similar on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, iOS does not have a directly equivalent option. There are some workarounds and apps given here: [Is there any way to change the snooze time for alarms on the iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29353/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-snooze-time-for-alarms-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Snooze option on the lock screen in iOS 7 - the snooze time is 10 min.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Launch the Calendar app from the Home screen of your iPhone or iPad.
Tap on the name of the event you'd like to change the default alert for (or add an alert if you have default alerts disabled).
Tap on the Edit button in the upper right hand corner.
Tap on Alert.
Choose the alert time you'd like the Calendar to remind you at and then tap on Done in the upper right hand corner.